# How to get values from textbox in EXTJS?

Tags: extjs

How to get values from text box in Extended JavaScript and store in temporary variable.
e.g.: var textVal=Textbox.val();

Comment: I found solution:

var textVal= Ext.getCmp('Textbox1').getValue();

Comment: You should avoid using getCmp() if possible. Use an itemId and selectors instead. That way you won't have to worry about potentially conflicting ids as your application grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`getValue()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-method-getValue) method:

> Returns the current data value of the field.

Comment: Elaborate it with an example.